# Insert series ending at last valid index in dataframe column. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe that contains a combination of null and numeric values in which each series of numeric values is always located together and is never interspersed with nulls. Such as:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan],
    'B': [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3],
    'C': [np.nan, 1, 2, 3, np.nan]
})

    A   B   C
0   1.0 NaN NaN
1   2.0 NaN 1.0
2   3.0 1.0 2.0
3   NaN 2.0 3.0
4   NaN 3.0 NaN
```

**Desired Output**
I'd like to create a second data frame with identical index and columns in which a defined series is inserted so that it ends at the index of the last non-null value for each column in df1.

Note that the length of the defined series will differ to the length of non-null values in each column. i.e.

```
new_data = ['A','B']

    A   B   C
0   NaN NaN NaN
1   A   NaN NaN
2   B   NaN A
3   NaN A   B
4   NaN B   NaN
```

**Current Approach**
My current approach achieves this by creating an empty dataframe, looping through each column, defining the index range and assigning the new data:

```
new_data = ['A','B']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df1.columns, index = df1.index)

for col in df2:
    end = df1[col].last_valid_index()+1
    start = end - len(data)
    df2[col][start:end] = new_data

    A   B   C
0   NaN NaN NaN
1   A   NaN NaN
2   B   NaN A
3   NaN A   B
4   NaN B   NaN
```

While this works, it feels somewhat brute force and I hoped to find a more elegant solution please.

Comment: Can there be multiple series in each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have only one stretch of non-NA per column (if not see alternative below).

One option using a reverse [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html), [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), and [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
m = df1.notna()

out = (m[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
       .apply(lambda s: s.map(dict(enumerate(new_data[::-1], start=1))))
       .where(m)
      )
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    A  NaN  NaN
2    B  NaN    A
3  NaN    A    B
4  NaN    B  NaN
```

Intermediates:

```
# m[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
   A  B  C
0  3  3  3
1  2  3  3
2  1  3  2
3  0  2  1
4  0  1  0

# ….apply(lambda s: s.map(dict(enumerate(new_data[::-1], start=1))))
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    A  NaN  NaN
2    B  NaN    A
3  NaN    A    B
4  NaN    B  NaN
```

#### alternative

If you can have multiple stretches of non-NAN, replace `cumsum` bu [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
dic = dict(enumerate(new_data[::-1]))

out = (df1.apply(lambda s: s.groupby(s.isna().cumsum()).cumcount(ascending=False).map(dic))
          .where(df1.notna())
      )
```

Example output:

```
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    A  NaN  NaN
2    B  NaN    A
3  NaN    A    B
4  NaN    B  NaN
5    A  NaN  NaN
6    B  NaN  NaN
```

Alternative input:

```
     A    B    C
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  1.0
2  3.0  1.0  2.0
3  NaN  2.0  3.0
4  1.0  3.0  NaN
5  2.0  NaN  NaN
6  3.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help with this. Your solution worked perfectly!